# CakePHP 2.0 Disable Routing Issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have my own routing rules in routes.php, defined for all the pages that should be accessible via URL, such as mywebsite/blog/ and mywebsite/blog/category/category-name, i.e. the structure of my whole website is covered by my custom routes.

Now, I have a lot of elements that make use of requestAction, such as

```
       $websiteabstract = $this -> requestAction(array(
        'controller' => 'assets',
        'action' => 'displayHomeAbstract'
       ));
```

This gives me an error Error: Controller could not be found, probably because I have not defined a route for /assets/displayHomeAbstract. But why do I have to define a custom route for that, when I explicitly state the name of the controller and the action? Shouldn't that bypass the routing altogether? 
Either I have not understand Routing at all. Or do I really have to define ALL the possible routes (even those that are only used by requestAction) in my routes.php? I mean, I don't want to allow users to directly access mywebsite/assets/displayHomeAbstract anyway, only via an Element.

Thank you

EDIT: Here is my routes.php http://pastebin.com/aAKBwNZJ
Please have a look at line 128, this is exactly what I do not want since /assets/displayHomeAbstract is ONLY accessed via requestAction.

EDIT: And this is the element, that makes the request: http://pastebin.com/0tK5dYJk

Comment: If you're having issues understanding the routing system, I would advise just leaving the default routes in place.  /controller/method/arg1/arg2/... Is there any reason you've redone the routing?

Comment: yes, I have redone the routing because I want to have things such as mywebsite/blog/2005/05/this-is-the-title which should map to the method view of the posts controller and pass two arguments.. whatever, it just made sense to redefine it and therefore to restrict possible url access. I have understood how to define new routes and all works fine, but I do not really understand why an array passed to requestAction still needs to undergo routing?

Comment: And I want to disable the default routing to evade SEO issues, as advised in the cookbook.

Comment: That's likely your problem, [as the cookbook warns](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#disabling-default-routes).  Can you paste your routing configuration in your question?  It's relevant to your problem.

Comment: Also, general advice, make it work, make it pretty, make it fast(/optimized).  Premature optimizations can cause needless headaches.

Comment: I have done that now.I mean the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after extensive discussion with the devs in IRC, I think I understand this well enough to explain to you:

You **do** have to define your custom routes for your requestAction in this case. requestAction is emulating a full request. It dispatches a request as if accessed using the string url every time, even when the url provided is an array. The book is referring to how when you have a custom route defined **in addition** to using the default routes (the last line of routes.php), you can use array urls to be agnostic of those routes. However, these array urls rely on the default routes.php in the /lib/ folder and are used to construct a url string. If you're going to have a custom routing pattern, you have to construct the url strings on your own.

Note: the comments below were from earlier versions of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that doesn't change anything. The thing is, that whole parameter stuff does not even apply to me, I am not passing anything to the function. Essential is the following passage, which makes me ask this question in the first place: "This allows the requestAction call to bypass the usage of Router::url which can increase performance.". So according to this, the Router should be bypassed and even I have no routing rules defined, it should work?!

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I'm not sure where I got the idea that you were trying to pass parameters through. You're right, provided a URL that way it should bypass the router. I'll do some research.

Comment: Alright, thanks.. I have not really grasped the routing system yet, still it is not that easily described in the book..

Comment: Have you tried (just for testing's sake) adding a Route to your controller's action and then doing the requestAction using the route? This would tell us if the problem is in the Action or the Route. So something like: `echo $this->requestAction('/articles/view/5');`

Comment: Yes, I have added the route   `Router::connect('/assets/displayHomeAbstract', array(
 'controller' => 'assets',
 'action' => 'displayHomeAbstract'
));` and now there is no more error, and if I do     `$this->requestAction('/assets/displayHomeAbstract/')` it works as well. But doing this, it just tells me that adding the route to routes.php solved the problem - actually the thing that I do not understand since routing should be bypassed.

Comment: Right. You definitely shouldn't have to add each requestAction route!

Comment: I have added my routes.php to the post, so you get an impression.

Comment: jose_zap in IRC mentioned something about the last line in your file, but I'm not sure its what you want. I will continue investigating.

Comment: Then it works, of course, because default routes are included. But I don't want to have that, I want to explicitly disable them to avoid SEO and other issues (see discussion above). It should be possibly because routing should be bypassed when using requestAction with arrays.

Comment: Okay. See my edit above for why you in this case actually do have to define your own routes. (or alternately, create a function that takes an array and maps it to your url scheme) Thanks to jose_zap and savant in IRC for help.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.. then I will define all those routes :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key to your problem is understanding the scope of Cake's routing and how it work.

When you define a route in CakePHP, it isn't just used for mapping URLs to controllers.  It's also used by the [Router](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php) for things like generating link addresses and, in your case, mapping the path supplied to [requestAction()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Core/Object.php#L46) to a controller.  Behind the scenes, Cake is creating a URL string based on your parameters, and then passes it off to the Router to find the correct controller.  Since no such route exists, it fails.

As a solution, I would actually recommend not using a controller for that logic.  Depending on what it does, a component or a helper may be a better place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is in accordance with the one of @swiecki!

Comment: Glad I could help.  When you get it working, I'd spend a bit of time thinking about your design.  It sounds odd to have a private controller whose only job is to construct those elements, a simple `$controller->set()` in a component might be sufficient.

Comment: Which Controller do you mean? I have Assets as a controller because I have a database table "assets" where I save all stuff such as static content (which is not static actually, because I might change it from time to time). For example, the abstract for the whole website, or my about description. I get that stuff with Elements. How would you introduce a Component here?

Comment: A [Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) is logic shared between controllers.  You could write a component to `loadModel('Asset')` and then `set('data_for_element')`, and simply include it in any controllers where you want to display data from the assets table.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 156. You commented out the line that loads CakePHP's default routes.